# How to create guess counter in guessing game

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to  make a number guessing game where when you guess the number right, it tells you how many guesses it took.

I've tried several loops but can't figure out how to get my "guesses" to increase.

```
import random

rand_num = random.randrange(1,201)


def guess_game():

    guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
    guesses = 1
    if guess == rand_num:
        print("Hit!\nIt took you " + str(guesses) + " guesses!")
    elif guess < rand_num:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
        guesses = guesses + 1
        guess_game()
    else:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        guesses = guesses + 1
        guess_game()

guess_game()
```

For example, desired output should be something like this:

```
"Hit! It took you 5 guesses"
```

But it only says 1 guesses no matter how many tries it took.

Comment: Your example code had two indentation issues, one of which put the call to `guess_game()` in the `else` part on a different level - Python cares about indentation, so you should as well!

Comment: put guesses varible outside the function ,it will work

Comment: Correct, I just fixed the indentation to make sure people are looking at the actual problem, not just a typo - answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `guess_game()`, you are essentially resetting the game.

Instead, you want to enclose your game in a `while` loop which it only exits when the game is over. I have written a working version for you here:

```
import random
rand_num = random.randrange(1,201)
def guess_game():
    guesses = 1
    while(True):
        guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
        if guess == rand_num:
            print("Hit!\nIt took you " + str(guesses) + " guesses!")
            return 0
        elif guess < rand_num:
            print("Your guess is too low.")
            guesses = guesses + 1
        else:
            print("Your guess is too high")
            guesses = guesses + 1

guess_game()
```

Comment: while(True) essentially tells the code to continue running that section forever. While is essentially an if statement, but instead of doing something once, it does something repeatedly until it is no longer true. The only reason that it doesn't is because of the return statement which tells the programs to exit that function completely when the guess is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you keep calling `guess_game()` after every guess, effectively starting a new game after every guess.

When the user finally guesses correctly, it's always after 1 guess in that new game and then all games end at once, but never does the code reach the line where it prints the number after more than one guess in any of those games.

There's many different ways to fix this, but the main issue here is that (like many new programmers) you didn't realise calling a function doesn't just get the program to jump to your new code, it creates an entirely new space for the program to work in (each call to the function gets its own 'scope') and returns from that once the function is done, with the previous scope unchanged in most cases.

Comment: Ahh that does make sense. Thank you. How can I make the program continue even after an incorrect guess then?

Comment: As in how can I give the user endless guesses and have the guesses count up as in "it took you x guesses" instead of down in a "you have x guesses left"

Comment: @ccolson4072 to allow the person to continue to guess you can wrap all the conditional logic in a while loop, with a break once they have the right guess.  Also, remove the recursive calls.

Comment: @DarrylG how would i code the while loop, though? everything i try just let's a response such as "guess to high" go on infinitely and i cant figure out how to only say that once but also let the user continue with the program

Comment: @ccolson4072 for testing have you made your guess range smaller to test your route such as random.randrange(1,5)  to quickly test your logic. 
 If you're stuck I could post the answer, but your code only requires a couple of tweaks.

Comment: @DarrylG well right now the range doesnt even matter because if i get one wrong guess it ends the program. i will change my range and try to figure it out myself but if i get stuck for sure i will let you know in a few mins

Comment: @ccolson4072 looks like someone did post the corrections you need. As you see they wrapped the conditional logic in a while loop and performed a break when the guess was correct.

Comment: @DarrylG i see. so why does while(True) work? what is it saying is true etc. (i'm kinda new so i feel like i should know this but i dont)

Comment: @ccolson4072 while(True) essentially tells the code to continue running that section forever. The only reason that it doesn't is because of the return statement which tells the programs to exit that function completely when the guess is correct.

Comment: @ccolson4072 while True is the typical way of getting an infinite loop.  You keep looping until some condition is met.  In this case the guess is correct, and a return statement is used in this case (a break would also have worked which is more typical).

Comment: @MatthewGaiser OH! ok that makes sense completely! why return 0 instead of returning false? in this case does 0=False and 1=True ?

Comment: @ccolson4072 the return was called just to escape the while loop. The return value is unimportant in this case.  A break statement could also have been used.

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you guys. Helped out a lot and this was also my first question ever.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Thank you guys. Helped out a lot and this was also my first question eve

Comment: @ccolson4072 In this particular case, it could just be `return` or `return "geese"` or whatever else you wanted. I just used 0 because I learned to program in C++. What return is doesn't matter in this case as you are doing nothing with the value you are returning. The 0 doesn't mean anything in this case. It is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is not working well because you have initialize `guesses=1` in function when you call the function in itself (Recursion) the value of variable guesses is reset.

```
import random    
rand_num = random.randrange(1,201)

guesses=0 #initialize it outside function


def guess_game():
    guess = int(input("Please enter your guess: "))
    global guesses 
    guesses+=1
    if guess == rand_num:
        print("Hit!\nIt took you " + str(guesses) + " guesses!")
    elif guess < rand_num:
        print("Your guess is too low.")
        guess_game()
    else:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        guess_game()

guess_game()
```